# XCode 5 vs XCode 6 animation changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation

I recently just upgraded to xcode 6 and suddenly a bunch of my code in my app doesn't work. What happened originally was if you touched to the left of the screen, your character would face the left, and if you touched to the right he would face the right. When a certain interaction happened, there would be a method that would check whether or not he was looking to the left or right and the animation would correspond accordingly. Now in XCode 6, he can look to the left but play the animation that correlates to the right, and when I click to the left again, he briefly looks to the left and then will only play the right animation. I have a sample of the part of the code I think that is malfunctioning, but I can't seem to troubleshoot why.

```
if (Stickman.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft6.png"])
    {
    Stickman.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft1.png"], nil];
    [Stickman setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    Stickman.animationDuration = .5;
    [Stickman startAnimating];


    }

    else
    {
    Stickman.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight6.png"];
    Stickman.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjRight1.png"],       nil];
    [Stickman setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    Stickman.animationDuration = .5;
    [Stickman startAnimating];

     }
```

Comment: Is the SDK version the same?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is bad:

```
(Stickman.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"BjLeft6.png"])
```

This is comparing addresses and `UIImage imageNamed` may not return the same instance of the image as `Stickman.image` received and `==` will fail.

Rarely is comparing instance addresses the correct solution when comparing for equality.

Comment: From looking it over it looks like it "should" receive the same instance, which worked in xcode5. Is there a better way to write it in xcode6?

Comment: 1. It is not Xcode, it is the app and the Apple frameworks. Xcode is a fancy editor/compiler, etc, it does not execute the code. 2. "From looking it over" is insufficient, under that criteria it should work. 3. Apple does not guarantee that the same instance will be returned. 4. Apple is free to change how `UIImage` works below the level it provided documentation. 5. the comparison does not work, that is final.